# Override Default Keyboard shortcuts in VSCT file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create simple extensions for myself and assign it an easy shortcut
Since I use my extension mostly in debug mode "F9" will be a handy keyboard shortcut but this shortcut is already assigned to "Debug.ToggleBreakpoint"

I am using below code but its not overwriting default keyboard shortcut

```
<KeyBinding guid="guidLWConfigCmdSet" id="cmdidAHSLWConfig" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="0x78" />
```

Is there any way to override the default shortcut for my extension using VSCT file or any code in the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this -- users don't like it when extensions hijack keys, and we don't want to make it easy for extensions to do it. You *can* use [EnvDTE.Command.Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.command.bindings.aspx) if you want to change bindings programmatically; the best approach might be to define your own command, and then rebind F9 to it. You might want to look at what [VsVim](http://www.github.com/jaredpar/VsVim) does for keybindings, since it also needs to let users customize what keys do.