# Is there a way to override Visual Studio Keybindings in extension?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am wondering if there is a way of overriding default Visual Studio Keybinding behaviours in my extension?

Basically I am developing an extension and I have quite a lot of keybindings set. But because of safety all of them have a "prefix" keys which come before the actual keys eg. Ctrl + Shift + Alt + E (prefix) then Ctrl + D.

I would want to remove those "prefix" keys, so I would just have the actual keys like Ctrl + D, I thought if I could check if those were pressed or something and if my action/command did some stuff then the default behaviour wouldn't go through, and if my extensions action doesn't go through it must do the default behaviour.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This similar thread: [Override Default Keyboard shortcuts in VSCT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652264/override-default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-vsct-file) mentions there isn’t an easy way to do this. Is [Command.Bindings Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.command.bindings?view=visualstudiosdk-2022&redirectedfrom=MSDN#EnvDTE_Command_Bindings) helpful?

Comment: @Tianyu I am sorry but those weren't so helpful because I still have to do this some way.... I am building an Emmet sort of extension for VS